# Determining the interrupt type in linux (edge-triggered vs. level-triggered)

Tags: linux, interrupt, kernel-module, interrupt-handling

I have a Linux kernel module that drives some piece of interrupt-driven custom hardware, working like a charm for many years. Now we upgraded the PC that is used to run the software and ran into some wired behavior that looks like a lost interrupt after some ten hours of operation. `cat /proc/interrupts` delivers

```
5:   1  XT-PIC-XT      bmc_interrupthandler0
```

on the old machine while the new machine tells me:

```
5:   1  IO-APIC-edge   bmc_interrupthandler0
```

- Do I get it right, that the interrupt is level-triggered on the old machine, while it is edge-triggered on the new one?
- Is it possible to switch the behavior from edge-triggered to level-triggered? And if yes, how is it done?
- In general, is it necessary to write a driver in a way that can deal with both interrupt operation modes?
- Is there some good extensive documentation about the linux interrupt handling that can be recommended?

Comment: Things seem to be way more complex than I first thought: http://www.jonmasters.org/blog/2007/12/12/everything-you-know-about-interrupts-is-wrong/